# how to append content to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, object, grafana

```
$http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'xyz'
                }).then(function onSuccess(response) {

                        console.log({"Data Response for dashboard": response});
                    var dashboardData = response.data;},
function onError(response) {
               deferred.reject(response);
                });
                return deferred.promise;};

json file is looks like that {
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "test",
  "_id": "test",
  "_version": 7,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "user": "guest",
    "group": "guest",
    "title": "test",
    "tags": [
      "test"
    ],
    "dashboard": "{\"id\":null,\"title\":\"dasdasd\",\"originalTitle\":\"sdasdasdas",\"tags\":[\"sdada\"],\"style\":\"dark\",\"timezone\":\"utc\",\"editable\":true,\"hideControls\":false,\"rows\":[{\"title\":\"Delivered\",\"height\":\"300px\",\"editable\":true,\"collapse\":false,\"panels\":[{\"error\":false,\"span\":4,\"editable\":true,\"type\":\"graph\",\"id\":8,\"datasource\":null,\"renderer\":\"flot\",\"x-axis\":true,\"y-axis\":true,\"scale\":1,\"y_formats\":[\"short\",\"short\"],\"grid\":{\"leftMax\":null,\"rightMax\":null,\"leftMin\":0,\"rightMin\":null,\"threshold1\":null,\"threshold2\":null,\"threshold1Color\":\"rgba(216, 200, 27, 0.27)\",\"threshold2Color\":\"rgba(234, 112, 112, 0.22)\"},}
}
```

now in above json i want to add following  in panel (_source.dashboard.rows.panel)  "panels": [

```
 {
      "id": 1,
      "span": 12,
      "editable": true,
      "type": "text",
      "mode": "html",
      "content": "<div class=\"text-center\" style=\"padding-top: 15px\">\n<img src=\"img/logo_transparent_200x.png\"> \n</div>",
      "style": {},
      "title": "Welcome to"
    }
  ]
```

so I am storing response.data into  variable named dashboarddata so how I can append above content in panel (_source.dashboard.rows.panel)

Comment: The JSON you want to add to is not JSON but a string. You need to JSON.parse(dashboard)

Comment: Please take more care formatting your post. I have just tried to format it but it makes no sense; statements end early, there's a `return` statement outside of a function, ... Please refer to the Markdown Style Guide for Stack Overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and improve your question.

Comment: Missing \ and other stuff